# Odd cross-validation score on RF, does it implies problems?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying out Random Forest on the Titanic dataset. Then I applied cross-validation to my model. I found that the scores are all '1.0'. This is a realistic score? Or does it implies that I have done something wrong? I have already tried SGD classifier. The CV score for SGD was '0.81', which, in my eyes, are more possible for an untuned classifier rather than '1.0'.

Despite I have done my research on the problem, I could not find an answer. I am new to Machine learning so please pardon me if I have asked a repetitive question/ made basic errors.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
forest_clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,random_state=42)
forest_clf.fit(X,y)
```

---

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(forest_clf, X,y, cv=3, scoring="accuracy")

 array([1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: Are you applying cross validation on training set? i.e. `X,y`

Comment: yes, I am. The X is the processed data, y is 'Survived'.

Comment: Okay...That's not cross validation.

Comment: @Onlyfood Your code looks fine. My guess is that your `y` is either all 1's or 0's or that there's some error in `X` or `y` in general. Or maybe calling fit on the classifier before passing it to `cross_val_score` is causing some unintended behavior. It's difficult to reproduce the error without the data set and exact preprocessing steps you've used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross validation does not run on complete training set, instead, you split the training set to N folds. You train on the (N-1) folds and validate on the remaining 1 fold. For each epoch the 1 fold is randomly picked.

You're getting 1.0 for each classification (assumed) because on training set your model predicts 100% accurate - either performs perfect, or you are overfitting.

You can use `sklearn.model_selection.KFold` to split the dataset.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep on trying to figure out which one it is.